# Are Serialisable record canonical constructor limited in the validation they can perform?

Tags: java, serialization

I converted a class to a record and deserialization stopped working correctly because of the validation I perform in the canonical constructor. This validation assumes that the constructor parameters are fully constructed (deserialized).

```
record SomeRecord(List<SomeType> list) implements Serializable, ... {
    ...
    public SomeRecord {
        validate(list); // fails (null pointer exception)
    }

    private static void validate(List<SomeType> list) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the deserialization process, it seems that the SomeType elements in list are not fully constructed. My validation function fails because fields of the elements are all default initialised (0, false, null ...). To fix the problem, I created a new constructor with an extra unused parameter. This constructor validates the list.

```
record SomeRecord(List<SomeType> list) implements Serializable, ... {
    ...
    public SomeRecord(List<SomeType> list, boolean notUsed) {
        this(list);
        validate(list);
    }

    private static void validate(List<SomeType> list) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It feel kind of clumsy to require an extra unused parameter to get a working solution. Is there another way to work around this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem as I understand it ([see here](https://godbolt.org/z/qfdPGf1de)).

Comment: @Slaw [This could be a reproducer](https://godbolt.org/z/cK66cTM1G). Or something completely different. Don't know.

Comment: @Slaw The problem is not about deserializing the array. It is about deserializing SomeRecord. Note that I have tried unsuccessfully to reproduce the problem using a simple test. In my simple test, SomeType elements of the list are correctly initialized.

Comment: My code deserializes a record (not specifically named `SomeRecord`, but it's a record). The only explicit array in that code is a `byte[]`, which is the _serialized_ record that is then deserialized.

Comment: Note: The answer which brought up [circular references with records and their unique(?) behavior regarding Java serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/serialization/serial-arch.html#serialization-of-records) was deleted by a mod. Just want to point out that seems to be the only case where the record component will be null despite it _not_ being null when the record was serialized. From some tests, the only time I could seemingly reproduce the OP's error is when a record referenced itself or if it had a circular reference with another object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm completely following... how about a static creation method:

```java
public static newSomeRecord(List<SomeType> list) {
    validate(list);
    return new SomeRecord(list);
}
```

Or make the unused param do something:

```java
public SomeRecord(List<SomeType> list, boolean shouldValidate) {
    this(list);
    if (shouldValidate) {
        validate(list);
    }
}
```

**P.S.**
Your original class look like it wouldn't compile, since a non-compact constructor would have to explicitly do the assignment. Perhaps you meant the following:

```java
record SomeRecord(List<SomeType> list) implements Serializable, ... {
    ...
    public SomeRecord {
        validate(list); // fails (null pointer exception)
    }
```

Comment: You are right about your P.S. I fixed the pseudo code.